# How to increase SWI terminal memory?

Tags: swi-prolog

In the default console window application of SWI Prolog - such as the one started by swipl-win.exe on Windows -

After executing one (or many) query that writes too much to the standard output, the 'oldest' lines cannot be read. That is - after a while, scrolling up won't show lines past a point.

Is there a way to increase the number of lines in the 'memory' of the SWI Prolog terminal?

Comment: This has not much to do with swi-prolog itself. This is likely a setting in the terminal program where the swi shell is running in.

Comment: I should've specified - I'm referring to the default console window application, such as the one given by swipl-win.exe. Since it's specific to SWI-Prolog there's no other possible tag, really

Comment: but that still runs *inside* a terminal, the terminal is not really part of the binary itself. Likely you can click right and have some options about the buffer size. (although it has been more than ten years since I was forced to work on a Windows machine :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option IMO is to put [protocol](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=protocol) at work. That way, you have a file that mirrors your console, for both input and output, and you can inspect at willing by means of any good text editor.

Comment: Thanks - for my purposes this solves the problem although it seems that the contents are not flushed to the protocol file very frequently

Answer (score 0):

This has not that much to do with the swi shell itself. The swi shell will normally just write characters to the standard output channel. It is up to the terminal program itself (this is, normally not implemented by swi itself). To capture that output, and do something with it, like displaying it.

For example the standard [Ubuntu terminal has an option to allow "unlimited scrolling"](https://askubuntu.com/a/385947/128894). There are similar options for other terminals like `konsole`. See for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/227744/128894) and [here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/scrollback.html).

An alternative is using a program like [**`tee`** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) that will print the output to the terminal, and store it in a file (or some other program) as well.

If the terminal is not moving that fast, you can use <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> in most terminals to temporary "freeze" scrolling, and thus give you the opportunity to see the content. This however does *not* pauses the program itself, and if you press <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> a second time, the output generated meanwhile that was already flushed out of the scroll buffer can not be retrieved anymore.